# Compare every element in two different-size dataframes and get added or deleted word in pandas

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I have a question for pandas dataframe operation

Suppose I have two different sized dataframe( they have same row count but don't have same size of columns

```
a =pd.DataFrame({"code1":['A','B','C','D'],"code2":['E','F','G','H']})
b= pd.DataFrame({"code1":['A1','B','C','D'],"code2":['E','F','G','N'],"code3":['A2','L','M','']})
```

For visualization:

```
a: code1 code2
0     A     E
1     B     F
2     C     G
3     D     H
b: code1 code2 code3
0    A1     E     A2 
1     B     F     L
2     C     G     M
3     D     N
```

My ideal output is to have a dataframe 'c' saying that:

```
c: addedword  deletedword
0   A1,A2      A
1   L
2   M
3   N          H
```

Basically, I want to compare every row in 'a' with corresponding row in 'b'. And then compare every element so that if there is added string or deleted string, then display to a new dataframe.

Answer (score 5):

Use set differences

```
g = lambda x: map(set, x.values)          # converts 2-D array to sets
f = lambda t: (t[1] - t[0], t[0] - t[1])  # t will be a tuple of sets
h = lambda y: map(','.join, y)            # stitch sets back together
pd.DataFrame(
    list(map(h, map(f, zip(*map(g, (a, b)))))),
    columns=['Added', 'Deleted']
)

   Added Deleted
0  A1,A2       A
1      L        
2      M        
3     ,N       H
```

Comment: Nice to see you back :-)

Comment: Hi @Wen.  My level of participation is still in question (-:

Answer (score 3):

By using `np.in1d`

```
pd.DataFrame({'addedword':[b.values[i][~np.in1d(b.values[i] ,a.values[i])]  for i in range(len(a))],'deletedword':[a.values[i][~np.in1d(a.values[i] ,b.values[i])]  for i in range(len(a))]})
Out[176]: 
  addedword deletedword
0  [A1, A2]         [A]
1       [L]          []
2       [M]          []
3     [N, ]         [H]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `set`, `apply` and `map` in easy steps:

Create a set of each row for both dataframes:

```
aset = a.apply(set, axis=1)
print(aset)
bset = b.apply(set, axis=1)
print(bset)
```

Output:

```
0    {A, E}
1    {F, B}
2    {C, G}
3    {H, D}
dtype: object
0    {E, A1, A2}
1      {F, L, B}
2      {C, M, G}
3       {, D, N}
dtype: object
```

Create lists of joined differences between above sets :

```
deletedword = pd.Series(map(lambda x: ",".join(x), aset - bset))
print(deletedword)
addedword = pd.Series(map(lambda x: ",".join(x), bset - aset))
print(addedword)
```

Output:

```
0    A
1     
2     
3    H
dtype: object
0    A1,A2
1        L
2        M
3       ,N
dtype: object
```

Finally, create a dataframe out of these lists:

```
outdf = pd.DataFrame({"addedword":addedword, "deletedword":deletedword})
print(outdf)
```

Output:

```
  addedword deletedword
0     A2,A1           A
1         L            
2         M            
3        ,N           H
```